# Subqueries and the sum/count

Tags: sql, count, sum, subquery, sql-server-2014

I am using SQL Server 2014 and am currently trying to come up with a query that would show essentially a vendors name, their profit, the customerID, and the ordertotal per customer as seen in

```
select top 10 
    v.name, p.ListPrice - p.cost as 'Profit', 
    oh.CustomerID,
    sum(od.orderquantity) as 'Customers Total Orders'
from 
    vendor v
join 
    product p on p.vendorid = v.VendorID
join 
    orderdetail od on od.ProductID = p.ProductID
join 
    SalesPromotion sp on sp.salespromotionid = od.salespromotionid
join 
    OrderHeader oh on oh.orderid = od.orderid
group by 
    v.name, p.ListPrice - p.cost, oh.CustomerID
order by 
    oh.CustomerID
```

and my results look like

```
 Green Lake Bike Company    13.76   100 1
    Team Athletic Co.   39.75   100 1
    G & K Bicycle Corp. 21.90   101 1
    West Junction Cycles    407.41  101 1
    G & K Bicycle Corp. 21.90   102 1
    Victory Bikes   3.12    102 1
    Victory Bikes   18.15   102 1
    Consumer Cycles 618.48  103 1
    G & K Bicycle Corp. 21.90   103 1
    Green Lake Bike Company 3.12    103 3
```

how ever if I use this the quantities will show up individually instead of being added, my question is should I use a subquery for this instead of typing out more stuff than I need to or can I get away with out using one and how to incorporate a Sum or count in there as I probably took the wrong function.

Comment: Could you provide a sample desired output?

Comment: And also provide the sample input.

Comment: With my Results I should be getting the Vendor Name, the Profit, the Customer ID and the Ordertotal for each customer ID but as above I have everything but the *order total*  as my Sum is not working properly, and I believe it has to be done with a sub query but I am not 100 percent sure if I can do it with out one.

Comment: You've only restated what you've already said in the post and have not provided either piece of information that Aaron and I requested.